# Is there a solution for BigQuery Editions + Lookerstudio broken tables (Error: 5938024)

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

We are using Lookerstudio + BigQuery. After switching our BigQuery plan to BQ Editions we're getting the following error on some of our Lookerstudio tables:

> Data Set Configuration Error
> Looker Studio cannot connect to your data set.
>
> Failed to fetch data from the underlying data set
>
> BigQuery error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. This is usually caused by a transient issue. Retrying the job with back-off as described in the BigQuery SLA should solve the problem: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla. If the error continues to occur please contact support at https://cloud.google.com/support. Error: 5938024

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: We’ve noticed that this error sometimes appears on tables that are using blends and have comparisons. Try removing the comparisons and check if the error persists.

Comment: We solved this by moving from the Standard plan to the Enterprise plan.

Comment: We identified the issue and looking for mitigation. Sorry for trouble.

Just to double check - do you happen to use VPC-SC?

Comment: In that case - enterprise edition should fix this. Standard edition doesn't support VPC controls per https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/editions-intro#editions_features. We will make sure the error is more readable going forward

Comment: Yes, we use VPC. That seemed to have been the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enterprise edition fixes this since Standard edition doesn't support VPC controls.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing seems to be related to the connection between Looker Studio and BigQuery. According to this [documentation](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/12182485?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Csteps-to-resolve), this error can be caused by connection issues. You can try these steps to resolve:

Edit the broken component and then add the correct data source.

Refresh the data source fields

Reconnect the data source.

Remove the data source(s) from the reports, and then add them back.

Create a new data source to see if that works.

Revoke and then restore Looker Studio's access to your Google account.

If none of these solutions work, you can try contacting Google Support for further assistance.